# How to track multiple instances of the same user (object)

Tags: php, object, irc

I'm writing an IRC bot in PHP, and I wanted to make a s little more sophisticated then most other bots.

I have the following classes in my application:

1. `Bot` - The actual bot class, it handles all of the functionality and commands the bots can get.
2. `Registry` - Global settings and variables, passed on to any functioning class so that I don't have to litter the global namespace with variables.
3. `Channel` - Defines the channel object, properties: `$name, $nicklist`, where `$name` is the channel name and `$nicklist` is an array of `User` objects.
4. `User` - Defines the user object, properties: `$nickname, $fullAddress`, where `$fullAddress` is the user's address in the form of `nick!user@host`.

So far so good, however, a user may be on multiple channels, and since I don't want to have multiple objects from the same user (as if a user, for instance, changes his nickname, I'll have to update multiple elements instead of just one).

How would I go about this, I was thinking about holding a grand user pool at the base of the `Bot` class, and pass these references to the channels, but I don't really know how to do that either :P

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I can paste my current code if you'd like (it's rather long so I rather not do it if no one needs it).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `Bot` object is the one that needs to do the tracking, have an array of `User` objects on it, and pass the pointers to those objects (aka `$bot->users['name']`) to the `Channel` object.

That way, the same pointer can be passed twice in case the user is already found on the users list.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a list of channel id's to you user and every time the user join to a new channel you will append the list with a new channel id so if a user leave an channel you will remove the channel id from his list.

Comment: But the point is to track the users on the channels, and not channels on the users, because I want to check for instance, if the user is privileged at a specific channel, and compare him to other users in that channel. It makes more sense to make a user list in every channel rather then a channel list in every user. (although the two can be combined)

Comment: Also, it causes the same problem. 2 users can be on the same channel, then I'd have to give the same object to 2 users.

Comment: You will add the channel id only not the instance of the channel object. From reqs an channel has many users, an user can join to more than one channel, also user can see channel names he joined so user has the channel names list.

Comment: Note this is not an IRC client, it's a bot. The bot is supposed to track the users on the channel it's on. The users only carry meaning as objects so that the bot can tell whether a user is on a channel, is he an op on that channel, and to be able to ban him from that specific channel if it detects problems from him on that channel. For that purpose, I don't care what channels the user is on, I only care what users are on my channels.